# How to prove that this series diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm pretty sure I need to use the comparison test here, but I have no idea what to compare it to. I also know that it diverges only from the answers at the back of my book, how should I know to test it for divergence and not convergence?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: $$\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \sim \frac 1n$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\sin{\frac{1}{n}}\cos{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$=\frac12 \sin{\frac{2}{n}}$$

$\text{Since } \sin(x) \ge \frac{2x}{\pi} \text{ for } 0 \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$:

$$\frac12 \sin{\frac{2}{n}} \gt \frac12 \cdot \frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \frac{2}{n} = \frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

and the sum of this diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as
$$\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^p\sin\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+\frac12\sum_{n=p+1}^q\sin\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+\frac12\sum_{n=q+1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)$$

Now, using Taylor series for large values of $n$
$$\sin\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)=\frac{2}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\frac12\sum_{n=p+1}^q\sin\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)= H_q- H_p$$ and if $q$ becomes large
$$\frac12\sum_{n=p+1}^q\sin\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)=\log \left({q}\right)+(\gamma-H_p) +\frac{1}{2
   q}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^2}\right)\to \infty$$